# How do I select format an active selection of words in a textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to explore how do I apply some formatting to only few selected words in a textbox but so far unable to accomplish this myself.

Somehow with the code I created below, I can only use it to select all the words in the textbox instead of just a few words I want.

It would be great if anyone can provide me a simpler/ existing codes that can help me solve this please ?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub ActiveTextRange()

Dim sld As slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim wordcount As Long, j As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long

wordcount = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).textFrame.TextRange.Words.Count

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
.textFrame.TextRange.Words(Start:=1, Length:=wordcount).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(230, 0, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might help. Key to this is being able to track the location of the specific text you want to change in amongst larger chunks of text; my suggestion is to format each bit of text as you add it to the shape. Cheers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ActiveTextRange()

    Dim vPresentation As presentation
    Dim vSlide As Slide
    Dim vShape As Shape
    Dim vAddThisText As String

    ' Create a new presentation, add a slide and a rectangle shape
    Set vPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add
    Set vSlide = vPresentation.Slides.Add(vPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    Set vShape = vSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 600, 300)

    ' Make the shape white with a 3pt dark red border
    vShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbWhite
    With vShape.Line
        .ForeColor.RGB = rgbDarkRed
        .Weight = 3
    End With

    ' Setup the shape to be left aligned, font color, top anchored, etc
    With vShape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
        .TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = rgbBlack
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.WordWrap = msoCTrue
    End With

    ' And now format the word red, which is the 7th character and is 3 long
    vAddThisText = "Hello Red World"
    vShape.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter vAddThisText
    With vShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(7, 3)
        .Font.Color.RGB = rgbRed
        ' and change other attributes if needed etc
    End With

End Sub
```

And the output is ...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Techno for your quick response and effort, but that is not what I want actually. I hope to be able to just highlight a few words in a any paragraph and apply a predefined formatting quickly. I looking for some codes if any, that works like Activewindow.selection.shaperange(1), where it takes whatever I select as active and format accordingly. Thanks anyway : )

Answer (score 0):

This colors the second and third words red in a Title placeholder. After Words, the first number is the starting position and the second number is the length:

```
Sub ColorWords()
  Dim objSlide As Slide
  Dim objShape As Shape
  For Each objSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each objShape In objSlide.Shapes
      If objShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If objShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle Or objShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle Then
          With objShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Words(2, 2).Font.Fill
            .Solid
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          End With
        End If
      End If
    Next objShape
  Next objSlide
End Sub
```

To color a word selection, use:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(Red:=255, Green:=0, Blue:=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I better understand the ask ... but I'm assuming in this response you're selecting text ... rather than just a shape itself. So you're editing the powerpoint, select some text **in** a shape, and want to run a macro to format(?) It should be as simple as creating the following in a code module (and then I created a custom access toolbar link to run the macro at the top of PowerPoint to make it quick):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ActiveTextRange()
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = rgbRed
End Sub
```

Before:

[image: before]

Select the text "Red" and run macro:

[image: after]

Btw ... if you want to select just the shape and have some logic choose the text, the concept is a mix of this and my first answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Techno, This line of code is exactly what I want "ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = rgbRed". I didn't know you can actually write Selection.TextRange directly, I have misunderstood that I actually have to write like ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange(1).TextFrame.Textrange, which is wrong in my case. Million Thanks again.